# Java Exceptions languages

Tags: java, exception

I am curious why some exceptions are thrown in english and some in french even I did not configure anything ? what are the reasons?

I use windows 7 (french) and  jdk1.7.0_25.
Thanks.

Comment: Most likely it depends on the lib that throws the error. the standard lib should have i18n translations for all languages. Those you see in your language. But some third party libs may have no i18n translations at all. There you get the exception message in the language that the  programmer used (which is English almost ever, but not always...).

Comment: @Timothy Truckle thanks for your reply, is there 's a way to confugure that?

Comment: I only care about java exceptions not third party libs

Comment: Have you tried setting the system (OS) region and language to English US and restarting your Application?

Comment: yes I tried but didn't change